# Retrieve message from DOM with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning Python and I am trying things with Selenium. Today I am trying to retrieve a message from the Spectrum chat of Star Citizen: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/spectrum/community/SC/lobby/1
I would like to retrieve the: div class="lobby-motd-message" because it gives good information.

This is my code but when I run it, it displays nothing... Can you help me to solve this problem ? Please. I will do more things with Selenium ( a Discord bot) but I need to retrieve this information first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)

url = "https://robertsspaceindustries.com/spectrum/community/SC/lobby/1"
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

try:
    info = browser.find_element_by_class_name("lobby-motd-message")
    print(info.text)
except:
    print("not found")

browser.close()
quit()
```

Comment: What elements do you want displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what element you want you might need to target and get it's text.

```
try:
    info = browser.find_element_by_class_name("lobby-motd-message")
    print(info.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text)
    
except:
    print("not found")
```

Outputs

```
Star Citizen Alpha 3.11 is LIVE - Discover more here !
```

All of it

```
print(info.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Outputs

```
<p>Star Citizen Alpha 3.11 is LIVE - Discover more <a href="https://robertsspaceindustries.com/comm-link/transmission/17786-Alpha-311" target="_blank">here</a> !</p>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer ! I works as you said when I put: print(info.get_attribute('innerHTML')) but still empty when I put: print(info.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text).

Comment: Remove the headless.

Comment: I removed and still empty. Is Selenium the best way to check if the messages changes ? (for a long time) because its open Firefox and its consumes ram. And I have to connect to my account because the future message I need is restricted.